# Why won't AVI2DVD load the audio stream?

Tags: windows-xp, avi, dvd-burning

Windows XP SP3

I have an .avi file. It is in a folder on my "C:" drive. There are no disallowed characters in either the folder or file name. It has audio as I have watched it on my computer. I want to burn it to a DVD.

When I load the file into AVI2DVD, no audio stream shows, and the program will not work without an audio stream. I have used the net extensively to try and solve this, with no success.

AFICT I have followed all instructions exactly, but no audio stream. Very frustrating.

Does anyone have a clue? Can you help me?

Comment: Are you sure that the file has a file extension. I have accidentally erased the file extension attempting to rename a file before and had a similar issue. Once I put the file extension back on, everything was perfect.

Comment: Thanks for that, but that's not the problem. There are 8 lower case letters and then .avi The file folder is flatry. There are no spaces or other characters. I have moved the files (.avi plus .srt) to different folders on my C: drive with no success. Regards,